# Redirecting from domain.com to www.domain.com keeping GET & POST data

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301

Currently my web site shows the same data if people go to domain.com or www.domain.com.

I would like to set up a redirect so all requests to domain.com will get sent onto www.domain.com. So a user who goes to domain.com will get redirected to www.domain.com. Just like what happens if you go to http://amazon.com/?a=b

I don't want to lose or corrupt any GET or POST data that is sent in the domain.com request.

What is the best way to do this? Should I use a 301 redirect? Will this cause the user's browser to re-send GET/POST data to the www.domain.com URL?

[EDIT]
Ok, Zaagmans says redirecting POST transparently to the user is not possible. So lets ignore POST for the moment. How should I redirect with just query string data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Redirecting Post Requests](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/26302/redirecting-post-requests.html) article explains this in detail.
A (possible) downside of the proposed **307** redirect is the fact that the browser will alert the user and present an option to proceed or to cancel the request.

Comment: Thanks for that article. 
http://www.domain.com$S$Q should do the trick?
It doesn't say whether I should use a 301 or 302. Any thought on which is best for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  For GETs, you'll need to use a 301, and the browser will need to re-request it.  If your GETs are idempotent (and they should be), this won't be a problem.  Search engines respect 301s in ways that they don't respect other 30x codes.

I don't know which web server you're using, but there are usually URL rewrite/redirect modules that will handle a lot of this for you.